# Are Control Flow Graphs(CFG) planar?

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

I notice there are different definitions for CFG(basic block or statement), so let's consider following definition:

> Given a program, each statement is a node in CFG, and $(u,v)\in E\iff \text{v is successor of u ,or u is branch and u's target is v}$

Due to such definition, each node has atmost two out-edges. So we can't construct a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_{5}$ directly, and I have no idea how to move on. I've searched the web and found [this](http://lmazy.verrech.net/2011/10/on-planarity-of-control-flow-graphs/), but I can't understand the examples. It looks like a different definition, for example, the last image seems to suggest that three `m(i)` are the same one, but in my opinion, they are executed one by one.

`Goto` is harmful to control flow, so I'm curious if we do not use `goto`, are CFGs always planar? If this is wrong, can we always write a programm whose CFG is planar without loss of function?

Comment: I think the question you're asking is whether or not *reducible* flow graphs are planar. What an interesting question! I feel like the answer should be "yes" and it should be provable using an argument based on interval analysis. I did a quick search, and I haven't found a proof or counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this is wrong, can we always write a program whose CFG is planar without loss of function?

Yes, we can.

Suppose we have an arbitrary CFG $G$, which is a finite graph.

> It is known that any finite graph can be embedded into a three-dimensional space.  - Wikipedia

Let's say for our CFG, we have a 3D embedding $E:G\mapsto\mathbb{R}^3$.

Of course, if we naively project such graph onto a plane $P$, it would not be planar in general.

However, two intuitions can help us see how we can always make a planar CFG functionally equivalent:

- With some techniques, it is possible to define our $E$ such that its projection $E_P$ on $P$ is **nice**, such that the **only reason** $E_P$ is not planar is that there are intersections between two edges (or should we say, the images of the edges). Such nicety excludes the following situations:

  - Two edges lie on the same line.
  - A node is passed through by an edge.
  - Three edges intersect at the same one point.
  - .etc
- There is a way to emulate an intersection of two edges using only planar structure.

  - Diagrammatically, for an intersection, we can make the following transformation $\tau$:

```
A  C         A'  D'
 \/    ==>    \ /
 /\    ==>     E
B  D          / \
             B'  C'
```

###### An example of $\tau$

Suppose in our diagram above, `A` goes to `D` and `B` goes to `C`. The following pseudo-code should work as the transformed version:

```
# A being replaced by
A': A; set is_from_A = true; goto E

# B being replaced by
B': B; set is_from_A = false; goto E

# E being
E: if is_from_A, goto D, else goto C
```

###### The sketch of proof

Theorem: for any program, there is a program whose CFG is planar that does the same stuff.

Proof.

- It is always possible to define a **nice** embedding for a CFG.
- The only possibility that the 2D projection of a **nice** embedding is not planar is that there are pairs of edges intersecting each other.
- We can create a program by exactly transforming the intersections with $\tau$. The resulting CFG is planar **and** does the same stuff as the original one.

QED.

A caveat is that this does not rule out the possibility that the resulting transformed planar CFG can be much more complex than the original version (having much more nodes and edges for example).

Comment: Is this  "With some techniques, it is possible to define our E such that its projection EP on P is nice" a theorem? And, It seems that your proof doesn't involve any property of CFG, unless only CFG satifies the claim above.

Comment: @LighT Yes. I am just rephrasing (in a weaker version) what Theorem (3.1) on P7 in *Introduction to Knot Theory* by Richard H. Crowell states: *Any polygonal knot is equivalent under an arbitrarily small rotation of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a polygonal knot in regular positions.*, where *in regular position* means *nice*.

Comment: @LighT "[...] doesn't involve any property of CFG" I believe that in the second intuition,  the transformation $\tau$ requires that we can create such object $\tau$ for the kind of objects we are considering, which is CFG/programs in our case, and that it preserves the equivalence of interest, which in our case means "programs that do the same stuff".

Comment: Thanks for your reference. I thought it carefully, and it's not obvious that $\tau$ always exists. If you want to introduce a new node **with two outedges** in CFG, you should write an IF statement at the same time.  One successor is its branch target and another is **next statement**. So, condition and statement position in code both matter, and I can't come up with a good solution.

Comment: @LighT I think you are right if we think of the `E`, `A'`, `B'` in my diagram as simple nodes. But in our case, the proof would remain valid if such node is a kind of *super node*, as long as it is planar. Suppose `A` jumps to `D` and `B` jumps to `C` in my diagram. To construct the transformed diagram, we can set a flag after `A` and `B` to indicate whether the source is `A` or `B`. `E` can then condition on such flag to direct the computation to the supposed branch.

Comment: @LighT "So, condition and statement position in code both matter, [...]" I am not sure if statement position really stands out as it might depend on the language we use to program. With some extra grammatical sugar (like, `goto`), we can always see nodes as freely movable stuffs independent of their actual positions in the string representation of the program, so long as we correctly label the statements and jumps to the correct labels.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

First:
If we use your definition of a CFG, they still can be non-planar. Consider the following (silly) piece of code:

```
void D(){}
void E(){}
void F(){}

void A(x){
    if(x == 0) D();
    else if(x == 1) E();
    else F();
}
void B(x){
    if(x == 0) D();
    else if(x == 1) E();
    else F();
}
void C(x){
    if(x == 0) D();
    else if(x == 1) E();
    else F();
}

int main(){
    int x = input();
    if(x == 0) A();
    else if(x == 1) B();
    else C();
}
```

You will find that the CFG looks something like this:
[image: CFG Graph]

Now notice that if you collapse the A0,A1 edge and the B0, B1 edge etc.
you get $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph. And thus according to [Wagner's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%27s_theorem) the graph is not planar.

The article you reference uses essentially the same trick. But instead of if-statements they use virtual methods to make a three-way decision between types.

Comment: thank you for your explanation!